# Ionic 5 angular - migrate ion-slides to swiper.js

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

I have received a **warning** for using `ion-slides` saying ion-slide is depricated and will be removed in ionic v7. and is suggest to use `swipper.js` instead.

Now I followed this [swiper.js](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/slides#swiping-with-style) tutorial on how to integrate swiper with Ionic-angular project.

**Installed swiper**

```
npm install swiper@6
```

**added styles**

```
@import '~swiper/swiper';
@import '~@ionic/angular/css/ionic-swiper';
```

**app Module**

```
import { SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    SwiperModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

**gallery.component.html**

```
<swiper>
  <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
</swiper>
```

**gallery.component.ts**

```
import SwiperCore from 'swiper';
import { IonicSwiper } from '@ionic/angular';

SwiperCore.use([IonicSwiper]);
```

and the **Error** I'm getting is:

> NG0304: **'swiper' is not a known element**

> NG0304: **'swiper-slide' is not a known element**

where do I import the missing components?

I have tried importing the `SwiperComponent`

```
import { SwiperComponent } from 'swiper/angular';

  declarations: [
    ...
    SwiperComponent
  ],
```

then I get an Error

> **Error:** Type SwiperComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Comment: wherever you have declared the galleryComponent in that module you will have to import swiperModule too

Answer (score 1):

> Error: Type *SwiperComponent* is part of the declarations of 2 modules

The issue above basically occurs when a component is declared in 2 different modules.

Remove the *SwiperModule* in your **app.module.ts** and add the *SwiperModule* in your gallery module. Your **gallery.module.ts** should have the *SwiperModule* like the example below.

**gallery.module.ts**

```
import { SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular';
imports: [
...
SwiperModule
],
```

Comment: does not fix the issue. and ignoring the error does not work either. for me I cannot make this sh** work. trying for the last 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this as well.  What helped me was the message in the console which a link to the migration information. See ion-slides (https://ionicframework.com/docs/next/api/slides), just make sure you switch to v6 in the header next to the Search bar if you don't use the link.  There are specific instructions depending on the framework you are using.

For Angular (https://ionicframework.com/docs/next/angular/slides), it looks like you are most of the way there.

Remove the SwiperModule from your app module and place it in your gallery module like @dom.macs suggested.

In your html make the following changes:

```
<ion-slides> -> <swiper>
<swiperSlide> -> <ng-template swiperSlide>
```

You do not need to import the SwiperComponent.

Based on your code snippets that should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had the same problem!

This issue is occuring because you're using an old version of **@ionic/angular**.

For Resolving this issue declare the swiper module in **app.module.ts**

then, update your @ionic/angular version to latest

> npm i @ionic/angular

Answer (score 0):

Like **Indraraj26** said in your question's comment section:

> wherever you have declared the galleryComponent, in that module, you will have to import swiperModule too

Also make sure to use `<ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 1</ng-template>` instead of `<swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>`.

Essentially, both, the `SwiperModule`, and **the component that is using `<swiper>`**, have to live in the same module.

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ... ,
    GalleryComponent,
    ... ,
  ],
  imports: [ 
    ... ,
    SwiperModule,
    ... ,
  ],
})
export class ...Module {}
```